# Conversion of the nvarchar value '3001822585' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-update, type-conversion, table-valued-parameters

I use following to import Excel file to SQL Server.

The Excel file has all the values as string. I am able to import the file except `Barcode`, `SalePrice` and `Price2`. I get error

> Conversion of the nvarchar value '3001822585'(barcode) overflowed an int column

Code:

```
         SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand
         (@"MERGE Inventory AS target
         USING (SELECT
            LocalSKU, ItemName, QOH, Price, Discontinued,Barcode, Integer2
            ,Integer3, SalePrice, SaleOn, Price2 FROM @source)
            AS Source ON (Source.LocalSKU = target.LocalSKU)
           WHEN MATCHED THEN
           UPDATE 
           SET ItemName = source.ItemName,
           Price = source.Price,
           Discontinued = source.Discontinued,
           Barcode = source.Barcode,
           Integer2 = source.Integer2,
           Integer3 = source.QOH,
           SalePrice = source.SalePrice,
           SaleOn = source.SaleOn,
           Price2 = source.Price2;", sqlconn);

           SqlParameter param;
           param = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", dr);
           param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
           param.TypeName = "dbo.InventoryType";

           sqlconn.Open();
           sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           sqlconn.Close();
```

Database::

```
 LocalSKU varchar(200),
 ItemName varchar(200),
 QOH int,
 Price decimal(19,4),
 Discontinued bit,
 Barcode int,
 Integer2 int,
 Integer3 int,
 SalePrice decimal(19,4),
 SaleOn bit,
 Price2 decimal(19,4)
```

`dbo.InventoryType` is:

```
   CREATE TYPE [dbo].[InventoryType] AS TABLE
   (
      [LocalSKU] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
      [ItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
      [QOH] [int] NULL,
      [Price] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
      [Discontinued] [bit] NULL,
      [Barcode] [varchar](25) NULL,
      [Integer2] [int] NULL,
      [Integer3] [int] NULL,
      [SalePrice] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
      [SaleOn] [bit] NULL,
      [Price2] [decimal](19, 4) NULL
   )
   GO
```

How to cast the datatype in table valued parameter? Example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Use unsignedInt datatype.

```
int range - 4 bytes, -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 
unsignedInt range - 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

Your barcode value **3001822585** is exceeding max int value **2,147,483,647** and so throws error

**Edit**

`unigned int` are not found in SQL Server , however MySQL supports it.
For SQL Server you will have to use **bigINT**

```
bigInt range - 8 bytes -2^63 to 2^63-1
```

So change data type of `Barcode` column to bigInt . If you think other column values can exceed int range , then change their datatype also.

Answer (score 2):

SQl Statement:

```
SELECT max( Mother_ID)+1 FROM Mother
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACKAW.jpg
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the nvarchar value '182512900911500120' overflowed an int column.

The problem is caused due to the number 182512900911500120 exceeds int range. If we convert in to bigint than it works.

i.e.

```
SELECT max(convert(bigint,Mother_ID))+1 as MID FROM Mother
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLSNR.jpg
Result
182512900911500121